# Creating BitmapImage throws missing key exception

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a view that displays an image with it's title and comment alongside it.
When I load up existing images I utilize this code:

```
        this.ArtifactIdentity = image.ArtifactIdentity;
        this.Comment = image.Comment;
        this.Name = image.Name;
        this.MediaIdentity = image.MediaIdentity;
        this.ImageArray = image.Image;
        Image = new BitmapImage();
        Image.BeginInit();
        Image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
        Image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        Image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(this.ImageArray);
        Image.EndInit();
```

When I execute the EndInit() it throw the exception missing parameter key.  The stack trace shows this:

```
  at System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey(Object key)
  at System.Collections.Hashtable.Contains(Object key)
  at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.ImagingCache.RemoveFromCache(Uri uri, Hashtable table)
  at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
  at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
```

So can anyone tell me why I am getting this exception when I am using code I've seen many others use with success and yet I get this exception???  I'm at a loss!

Comment: What is the exact exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article that was written by Bradley Grainger [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/07/exceptions_thrown_by_bitmapimage_and_bitmapframe.html) and had a list of exceptions caused by loading a BitmapImage.  What SLaks stated is correct but in Brad's article he stated that the next exception (No Imaging component suitable to complete...) is frequently showing up on Windows 7 machines.  The exception suggests that the metadata is corrupted in some way.

My solution took some testing to confirm but basically if I take the byte stream, save it to a temp file, then use that tempfile to populate the BitmapImage I can successfully load it without exceptions.

It is not the most desired solution but it does the one thing that I needed: it displays the image without exceptions!

Comment: I'm upvoting this because sometimes a kludge is all you need to get past the problem and get the work done. I don't like it either :)

Answer (score 12):

This is caused by a bug in WPF, in `BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()`:

```
if ((CreateOptions & BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache) != 0)
{
    ImagingCache.RemoveFromImageCache(uri); 
}
```

If you specify `IgnoreImageCache`, but don't load from a URI, it breaks.

Just get rid of that flag; it only applies when loading from URLs.

Comment: When I remove that from the options I get a new exception:No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.  I have either bmp, jpg, or png as the possible source.  Is this why I get this exception?

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: That might be because it can't figure out what format to load as.  What's the stack trace? What format are you loading?

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: Try `bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346766/34397