# WPF - Wrong image visualization changing it programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two windows:

- MainWindow loads the images in a DataGrid and shows a preview of them
- ImageWindow is open when double-click on a row in a DataGrid showing the related image

What I would like to achive is that when the ImageWindow is open, and the user press the left or right key button, the ImageWindow will load respectively the previous or next image in the DataGrid.

This is the what I did so far:

**ImageWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ImageBrowser.ImageWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageBrowser"
    xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:ImageBrowser.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ImageWindow" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid x:Name="GridContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="ClosedCurveButton" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightBlue" ToolTip="Draw closed curve" Click="ClosedCurveButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Source="/Resources/spline.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ClosedCurveInfoButton" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightBlue" ToolTip="Show curves info" Click="ClosedCurveInfoButton_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Source="/Resources/statistic.png"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" x:Name="canvasContainer" Height="{Binding ElementName=currentImg, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=currentImg, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image x:Name="currentImg" Source="{Binding ImageBpm}"  Mouse.MouseEnter="CurrentImg_MouseEnter" Mouse.MouseLeave="CurrentImg_MouseLeave" 
           Mouse.MouseMove="CurrentImg_MouseMove" ContextMenuOpening="CurrentImg_ContextMenuOpening" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
            <Image.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Set LandMark" Click="AddLandMark_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding MousePosition}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Image.ContextMenu>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
    <Label x:Name="CoordinatesLabel" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Image Ref x: {0} y:{1} - Grid Ref x: {2} y:{3}</Label>
</Grid>
```

**ImageWindow.cs**

```
public partial class ImageWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private MainWindow _parent;

    public event EventHandler GoPrevius;

    public event EventHandler GoNext;

    private BitmapImage _imageBpm;

    public BitmapImage ImageBpm
    {
        get { return _imageBpm; }
        set
        {
            if (_imageBpm != value)
            {
                _imageBpm = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageBpm));
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    public ImageWindow(MainWindow parent, string imageName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = imageName;
        _parent = parent;
        _parent.NewImage += _parent_NewImage;

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void _parent_NewImage(object sender, NewImageEventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveLandMarks();
        ImageBpm = CreateImageSource(e.NewImageName);
        Title = e.NewImageName;
        ReloadLandMark(_parent.ImagesMap[Title]);
    }
    
    private BitmapImage CreateImageSource(string imageName = "")
    {
        string image = imageName.Equals("") ? Title : imageName;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(_parent.ImagesMap[Title].ImageBytes))
            {
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error loading image: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

        return bitmapImage;
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            GoPrevius?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            GoNext?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public class NewImageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string NewImageName { get; set; }

    public NewImageEventArgs(string newImageName)
    {
        NewImageName = newImageName;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public Dictionary<string, LandMarkedImage> ImagesMap { get; } = new Dictionary<string, LandMarkedImage>();

    public event EventHandler<NewImageEventArgs> NewImage;
    
    private void ImageWindow_GoNext(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageGrid.Items.Count - 1 > ImageGrid.SelectedIndex)
        {
            ImageGrid.SelectedIndex++;
            Item item = ImageGrid.SelectedItem as Item;
            NewImage?.Invoke(this, new NewImageEventArgs(item.Name));
        }
    }

    private void ImageWindow_GoPrevius(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageGrid.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            ImageGrid.SelectedIndex--;
            Item item = ImageGrid.SelectedItem as Item;
            NewImage?.Invoke(this, new NewImageEventArgs(item.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

The strange behaviour that I am obtaining is that the first time I press the left or right button, the image does not change. I am sure that events are correctly triggered because I followed in debug and because the Title of the ImageWindow changes taking the name of the new image, but the image itself does not follow.

Here an example:
[image]

Double-click on gazebo image from MainWindow:
[image]

Left key button pressed:
[image]

I read that could be related to an "aggressive" caching of the BitmapImage, so I tried to use the flag `BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache` but then the software start to crash throwing missing key exception. I found reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675976/creating-bitmapimage-throws-missing-key-exception) that I cannot use that flag because seems it can be used only if the image is loaded from URI.