# IO.Stream to Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to read an image from a resource only DLL file. I am able to read the image name and image bytes, but How do I set the `Image` control to stream buffer? In windows form, I know I can use this :

```
pictureBox1.Image=new System.Drawing.Bitmap(IOStream);
```

since there is no Drawing namespace in wpf, how can I achieve the same thing?

Comment: Yes there is, just add the reference to System.Drawing.dll using the VS "Add Reference" dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WPF you probably have an `Image` element in your xaml. The `Source` can be any `BitmapImage`. You can bind a `BitmapImage` from your ViewModel, where you can create an instance from a `Stream` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346727/convert-memory-stream-to-bitmapimage).

Answer (score 20):

In WPF, you can set the `Source` property of an `Image`, as in this example:

```
Image image = new Image();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
                                      BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                      BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

Where `byteArray` is the array of bytes with the source of the image.

Comment: @TanujWadhwa Sorry, I misunderstood the question, edited to reflect this.

Comment: what I was looking for.