# How can display an image Profile for tweetinvi

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

I've tried it review images through GetProfileImageStream Next CODE

```
pic.Image = User.GetProfileImageStream(user, ImageSize.bigger);
```

In the language C# form !! out error

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State 
>   **Error CS0029** Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.IO.Stream'` to `'System.Drawing.Image'`

What is the problem?
Thank

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857325/io-stream-to-image-in-wpf

Comment: thank DhiaTN  the good

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is my solution I used to display my profile photo inside a button icon.

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials(TwitterSettings.ConsumerKey, TwitterSettings.ConsumerSecret, TwitterSettings.AccessToken, TwitterSettings.AccessTokenSecret);
var user = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
var getProfilePic = user.GetProfileImageStream(Tweetinvi.Models.ImageSize.normal);
IDD_POST_TWEET.Iconimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(getProfilePic);
```