# Get cutout of image data in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

It possible get cutout of image data. 
If I know:

```
byte[] ImageData;
int width;
int height;
```

Basically I try find how get inner section of image from `byte[]` source.

For example I have image which is w: 1000px and h: 600px. And I want `byte[]` middle section 200*200px in `byte[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to know how many bytes in your array represent one pixel. The following assumes that you have an RGB image with 3 bytes per pixel.

Then, the array-index of the first byte that represents the top-left corner of your cutout is represented as

```
int i = y * w + x
```

where `y` is the `y`-coordinate of the cutout, `w` is the width of the entire image and `x` is the `x` coordinate of the cutout.

Then, you can do as follows:

```
// cw: The width of the cutout
// ch: The height of the cutout
// x1/y1: Top-left corner coordinates

byte[] cutout = new byte[cw * ch * 3]; // Byte array that takes the cutout bytes
for (int cy = y1; cy < y2; cy++)
{
    int i = cy * w + x1;
    int dest = (cy - y1) * cw * 3;
    Array.Copy(imagebytes, i, cutout, dest, cw * 3);
}
```

This iterates from the first to the last row to be cut out. Then, in `i`, it calculates the index of the first byte of the row in the image that should be cutout. In `dest` it calculates the index in `cutout` to which the bytes should be copied.

After that it copies the bytes for the current row to be cut out into `cutout` at the specified position.

I have not tested this code, really, but something like that should work. Also, please note that there's currently no range checking - you need to make sure that the location and dimensions of the cutout are really within the bounds of the image.

Comment: Thank you, this is absolutely what I want

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert it to an an image first, you can use this code I found on [Bytes.Com](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/214172-how-clip-portion-image)

> The following code works for me. It loads a .gif, draws the 30 x 30
>   section of the gif into an offscreen bitmap, and then draws the scaled
>   image into a picturebox.

```
System.Drawing.Image img=... create the image from the bye array ....
Graphics g1 = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g1.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
g1.Dispose();

Graphics g3 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g3.DrawImageUnscaled(img, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

Graphics g2 = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
g2.Dispose();

g3.Dispose();
img.Dispose();
```

You can use this question to turn your byte[] into an image : [Convert a Byte array to Image in c# after modifying the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444421/convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-c-sharp-after-modifying-the-array)

Comment: Thank you for response, unfortunately i am trying not use System.Drawing, so I accept Thorsten-dittmar solution, because is use only low level .net libaries. But thanks again