# display images in asp.net dynamically from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, wcf, arrays

I am dynamically creating controls in c# code of my asp.net website. I want to create a image control and display a image which is derived from byte array got from wcf service. I tried to convert the byte array in to image and save in a location with the following code but it does'nt work.
Can any one help me!

```
 public System.Drawing.Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444421/convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-c-sharp-after-modifying-the-array

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390983/convert-from-binarydata-to-image-control-in-asp-net

Comment: No need to first convert the byte stream into an image just to save to disk. Just save all the data directly to your location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\test.jpg", BYTE_ARRAY_OF_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're just missing the [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx) method:

```
public string byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
  string saveLocation = "<Path to save image to>"; // e.g. c:\mywebsite\image23.png
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
  System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
  returnImage.Save(saveLocation);
  return saveLocation;
}
```

Then use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to pass the url of the saved file location to an `asp:Image` control.

I should just mention that if you already have a byte array - ***instead of creating an `image` object just for saving the bytestream*** - just put the bytestream inside the `ImageUrl` of the `asp:image` control like this:

```
image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayIn);
```

Comment: @Annamalai - It should work fine, please show us how you set the URL after receiving the string. Anyways, I added another option for you which doesn't require saving the file to the disk.

Comment: Base64 encoded images for data uri's must be on a single line for some browsers. IIRC Convert.ToBase64String split the lines.

Comment: In any case, data uri's cannot be cached so this is not recommended due to performance penalty.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Haven't encountered any problems with ToBase64String causing line splitting but good to know if that ever comes up. About the performance penalty, saving all the images to the disk (and only storing a string URL in the DB) is *always* the best practice, but in cases such as OPs - it's not always possible

Answer (score 4):

Thats nice. There is no need of creating an image object. 
This worked for me:

```
image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayIn);
```

Comment: Prakash, this question is very old. Make sure next time its a active question. GL!